# Dynkin-diagrams package labels problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, pgfkeys

i'm struggling with the labels of some biforcate dynkin-diagram

my code is the following

```
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\begin{document

\begin{center}
 \begin{dynkinDiagram}
  \dynkin[labels={m \cosh \theta, 1,2,3,,n-2,n-1,n,n+1}, scale=1.8, extended]D{*ooo...oooo}
 \end{dynkinDiagram}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

but my output looks  like this. unlabel

[image]

I would really appreciate some help, I have tried different combinations but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues: first you can't use `\dynkin` inside of a `dynkinDiagram` environment, you have to choose one or the other. Second for some reason the label list parser does not like `\cosh`, so you can replace that with `\text{cosh}`. To add a bit of space around the operator I added `\,` in the code below.

To position the labels I added `label directions={}` in the example below.

Note that I don't know anything about Dynkin diagrams, so probably the end result is not fully correct - but it does have labels.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
 \dynkin[labels={m\,\text{cosh}\,\theta,1,2,3,,n-2,n-1,n,n+1},
         label directions={,,left,,,,right,,},
         scale=1.8,
         extended] D{*ooo...oooo}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Following the comment from egreg below, you can also robustify `\cosh` with `etoolbox` to make the command survive processing by `dynkin-diagrams`. This allows to use the original command instead of a poorly spaced `\text{cosh}`. Note that if you want to use other non-robust commands then you need to robustify those separately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\robustify{\cosh}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
 \dynkin[labels={m\cosh\theta,1,2,3,,n-2,n-1,n,n+1},
         label directions={,,left,,,,right,,},
         scale=1.8,
         extended] D{*ooo...oooo}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There should be a bit of space around "cosh".  Instead of using `\text`, you can use `\operatorname{cosh}`.  (This may require `amsmath`.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I agree that the original spacing was not good. `\operatorname` resulted in the same error as `\cosh` itself (`! Argument of \XC@definec@lor has an extra }.`) which probably has to do with some parsing either by TikZ or by `dynkin-diagrams` itself. I used `\,` as an alternative, I guess the spacing is more acceptable now.

Comment: Thanks but sadly I cant get this to work yet.   I get the following compilation error: '! Pacakge pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/ on background layer' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.'

Comment: @DRkangoroo did you try the document from my answer, without any changes or additions? Do you get the error also in that case? If you don't get the error with this code, then the error is caused by some other part of your code. If you do get the same error, then there is probably some version problem and you need to update your packages (either `tikz` or `dynkin-diagrams` or both). If you use MikTeX on Windows then you need to update both in 'user' and 'admin' mode to be sure that all packages are fully updated.

Comment: Yes, I did try it without any modifications but i get the same error, I'm using lualatex on Linux. I just reinstalled both pacakeges but the error persisst. I'm going crazy.

Comment: Maybe your packages or the kernel are too new, that also breaks code occasionally. I use TeX Live 2019 installed with `apt` (on Ubuntu). It works fine with LuaLaTeX as well (I just tested that). Which type of installation (distribution package manager or vanilla `tlmgr`) do you use? Which compiler version? I use LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian), dynkin-diagrams.sty 2020/04/30, tikz.sty 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).

Comment: At the moment, Overleaf gives the same error with the code above, so that should help to pin down the problem.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay I just tried on Overleaf, LuaLaTeX, TeX Live 2020 (you can set the TeX Live version in the Overleaf menu), and my code works without problems. XeLaTeX and pdfLaTeX also both work. Overleaf reports an error in the editor that `\theta` is not in math mode but that is a false positive and doesn't affect the compilation.

Comment: @Marijn: oops, you are right. I don't know how to track down the problem now.

Comment: @Marijn The problem with `\cosh` is that `dynking-diagrams` abuses `xstring` and so in many instances it tries full expansion which dramatically fails if the list contains tokens that don't survive `\edef`. Among them there is `\cosh`. Better solution: load `etoolbox` and do `\robustify{\cosh}` in the preamble.

Comment: @egreg thanks for your comment, I have added it to the answer.

Comment: @Marijn: Of course your code should work without robustify, so I have a bug. I just submitted an update to the dynkin-diagrams package to get rid of many expansions. Once the update gets through, I think it will work as it should with your code.

Comment: That update is on CTAN. Your code, working without robustify, is an example on page 10 of the documentation.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay although it's mostly code from the OP, I'm still happy to be a part of a package manual on CTAN :) and nice to see that the bug is resolved so quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way that might work. We can create a Dynkin diagram environment, put in place the labels that seem to work ok, and then for the difficult label, use TikZ directly inside the environment. Maybe that is more stable than using the labels from my package. (It gives the same picture as above.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{dynkinDiagram}[labels={,1,2,3,,n-2,n-1,n,n+1},
         label directions={,,left,,,,right,,},
         scale=1.8,
         extended] D{*ooo...oooo}    
\node[left] at (root 0) {\(m\,\cosh\theta\)};
\end{dynkinDiagram}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```